# Setter concatenates value twice separated by comma

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, liferay, getter-setter

I'm trying to pass a value ferm a jsp back to the bean. I create an action url with several parameters and they are all set correctly but the company name is set to "companyName, companyName" instead of just "companyName"

This is my url

`var url="<liferay-portlet:actionURL><liferay-portlet:param name='struts.portlet.action' value='/reg/submitStep1'/><liferay-portlet:param name='isSimplified' value='true'/></liferay-portlet:actionURL>&customerNo=" + custNo + "&companyName=" + companyName;`

I get the company name variable from the text field using jquery. The text input's id is companyName

```
var companyName = $('#companyName').val();
```

When I print it out `using console.log(companyName);` the value is fine, not concatenated twice.

In the setter, however, the value of the String is set to "companyName, companyName". All otherparameters (`isSimplified`, `customerNo`) are fine. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is it set to litteraly companyName (`companyName ,companyName`) or to the value? (e.g. `Apple, Apple`)?

Comment: It's set to the the value

Comment: May we see the whole class then (the parts, that modify your fields)?

Comment: `public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
  this.companyName = companyName;
 }`
It's just a simple setter, the value of the fields is not modified

Comment: It seems you are passing companyName as url parameter and form parameter as well.

Comment: @Pankaj Kathiriya you are right. Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing companyName as url parameter and form parameter as well, hence you are getting both parameters on server side.

Keep only one parameter either as url parameter or as form parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I am migrating my health domain application from struts 1.x to struts 2 and its a very big and mature application.
so finally i created below working code to overcome concatenates value twice separated by comma in case if duplicate parameter is passed.
    I created below generic method in my Util class to overcome 
    this issue for all models thoughout my whole application,
    Call this method from your Action class validate method
    Note : it will give priorty to url parameter rather than form parameter, which was my requirement.
 Here is my  customized method:

```
public static void refineModel(HttpServletRequest request , Object modelObject) {
                           Enumeration enumeration = request.getParameterNames();
                           while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                               String parameterName = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
                               String parameterValue = request.getParameter(parameterName);
                               try {
                                   if (modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(parameterName) != null && 
                String.class.isAssignableFrom(modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(parameterName).getType())) {
                                           Field field = modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(parameterName);
                                           field.setAccessible(true); // to access private variables also
                                           field.set(modelObject, parameterValue );
                                   }
                               } catch (Exception e) {
                                   //not required
                               }
                           }
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

To overcome from this problem , finally i created interceptor and called it just after the model interceptor in stack

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        ValueStack stack = invocation.getStack();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Iterator<Object> iterator = stack.getRoot().iterator();
        try {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Object actionObject = iterator.next();
                try {
                    if (ActionSupport.class.isAssignableFrom(actionObject.getClass())) {
                        if (invocation.getAction().getClass().getMethod("getModel", null) != null) {
                            Method modelMethod = invocation.getAction().getClass().getMethod("getModel", null);
                            Object modelObject = modelMethod.invoke(actionObject, null);
                            sb.append("\n*********RefineModelInterceptor**************");
                            sb.append("\n********** " + modelObject.getClass().getName());

                            Enumeration enumeration = request.getParameterNames();
                            while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                                String parameterName = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
                                String parameterValue = request.getParameter(parameterName);
                                try {
                                    if (parameterName.matches("^(.*)\\[\\'(.*)\\'\\]$")) {
                                        String mapName = parameterName.substring(0, parameterName.indexOf("["));
                                        String mapIndex = parameterName.substring((parameterName.indexOf("'") + 1), parameterName.lastIndexOf("'"));

                                        if (modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(mapName) != null) {
                                            Field field = modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(mapName);
                                            field.setAccessible(true); // to access private variables also
                                            if (HashMap.class.isAssignableFrom(modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(mapName).getType())) {
                                                HashMap<String, String> tempHashMap = (HashMap) field.get(modelObject);
                                                String hashMapValue = tempHashMap.get(mapIndex);
                                                sb.append("\n"+parameterName+" **earlier** " + hashMapValue);
                                                sb.append("\n"+parameterName+" ****now**** " + parameterValue);
                                                tempHashMap.put(mapIndex, parameterValue);
                                                field.set(modelObject, tempHashMap);
                                            } else if (TreeMap.class.isAssignableFrom(modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(mapName).getType())) {
                                                TreeMap<String, String> tempHashMap = (TreeMap) field.get(modelObject);
                                                String treeMapValue = tempHashMap.get(mapIndex);
                                                sb.append("\n"+parameterName+" **earlier** " + treeMapValue);
                                                sb.append("\n"+parameterName+" ****now**** " + parameterValue);
                                                tempHashMap.put(mapIndex, parameterValue);
                                                field.set(modelObject, tempHashMap);
                                            }

                                        }
                                    } else if (modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(parameterName) != null && String.class.isAssignableFrom(modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(parameterName).getType())) {
                                        Field field = modelObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(parameterName);
                                        field.setAccessible(true); // to access private variables also
                                        sb.append("\n"+parameterName+" **earlier** " + field.get(modelObject));

                                        boolean notFoundSetterMethod=true;  
                                        /* below code is to invoke the setter method so that if any functionality return in setter method could be sustained 
                                            if failed in finding setter method than directly set value on the field 
                                        */
                                        try {             
                                               Method method = modelObject.getClass().getMethod("set" + org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.capitalize(field.getName()), String.class);
                                               notFoundSetterMethod=false;  
                                               method.invoke(modelObject, parameterValue);
                                               sb.append("\n"+parameterName+" ****now**** " + field.get(modelObject));
                                                 } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                     notFoundSetterMethod=true; 
                                                    //not required
                                                 }
                                        if(notFoundSetterMethod){
                                            field.set(modelObject, parameterValue);
                                            sb.append("\n"+parameterName+" ****now**** " + field.get(modelObject));
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    //not required
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        //break; .. should we really break since got the action object ? 
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //not required
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //not required  
        }
        sb.append("\n**************************************\n");
        logger.debug(sb.toString());
        return invocation.invoke();
    }
```

below is my stack:

```
<interceptor-stack name="myCustomizedDefaultStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="datetime"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="refineModelInterceptor"/>  <!-- custom interceptor for removing duplicate parameter issue-->
                <interceptor-ref name="validation"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="workflow"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
```